# Disable/Enable Azure functions based on regions

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have a .net Azure function project which includes multiple functions such as EventGridTrigger function, BlobTrigger function etc. Few trigger functions in the project needs to be enabled only for specific regions. Is it possible to enable/disable trigger functions based on regions through app settings ?

```
[FunctionName("CosmosDBFunction")]   //enable only in US-west
public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger()])
{}

[FunctionName("EventGridFunction")]   //enable only in US-east
public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent)
{}
```

Edit:

I'm trying to disable in "isolated" Azure functions via appsettings.json within the project. The "[Disable]" and AzureWebJobs.$FunctionName.Disabled properties are not working from appsettings.json, though it is working if mentioned in azure portal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Disable` attribute, which dynamically disables specific Functions based on app settings.

For example:

```cs
[Disable("FUNCTION_DISABLED")]
[FunctionName(nameof(EventGridFunction))]
public static void Run(...
```

Each regional deployment will then set the `FUNCTION_DISABLED` setting to `true` if the Function should be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works when I create in-process azure function. I'm surprised to see it is not working in isolated process azure functions. Have you tried with isolated functions ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to disable/Enable Azure functions based on regions by using PowerShell command. I could able to achieve this by using `Update-AzFunctionAppSetting` command wherein all the functions of the mentioned location will be [Disabled - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=powershell#disable-a-function).

#### Subscription Level

```
$GetFunction=Get-AzFunctionApp -SubscriptionId <SUBSCRIPTION_ID>
$ResourceGroup=($GetFunction).ResourceGroupName
$Name = ($GetFunction).Name
For($I=0;$I -lt $ResourceGroup.count;$I++) {
    $FunctionDetails=Get-AzResource -ApiVersion "2022-03-01" -Name $Name[$I] -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup[$I] -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions"
    if($GetFunction[$I].Location -eq "<YOUR_REQUIRED_LOCATION>"){
        For($J=0;$J -lt $FunctionDetails.count;$J++){
            $Function=$FunctionDetails[$J].ResourceName
            $FunctionName=$Function.Substring(($Function.IndexOf("/")+1),($Function.length-($Function.IndexOf("/")+1)))
            Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name $Name[$I] -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup[$I] -AppSetting @{"AzureWebJobs.$FunctionName.Disabled" = "true"}
        }
    }
}
```

#### FunctionApp Level

```
$FunctionDetails=Get-AzResource -ApiVersion "2022-03-01" -Name <FUNCTIONAPP_NAME> -ResourceGroupName <RESOURCE_GROUP> -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions"

$Function=$FunctionDetails.ResourceName | Where-Object {$FunctionDetails.Location -eq "<YOUR_REQUIRED_LOCATION>"}

For($I=0;$I -lt $Function.count;$I++) {
$FunctionExtract=$Function[$I]
$FunctionName=$FunctionExtract.Substring(($FunctionExtract.IndexOf("/")+1),($FunctionExtract.length-($FunctionExtract.IndexOf("/")+1)))
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name <FUNCTIONAPP_NAME> -ResourceGroupName <RESOURCE_GROUP> -AppSetting @{"AzureWebJobs.$FunctionName[$I].Disabled" = "true"}
}
```

***SAMPLE RESULTS:***

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Replace `-AppSetting @{"AzureWebJobs.$FunctionName.Disabled" = "false"}` to true to enable it again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to do it from the c# code via appsettings. "AzureWebJobs.$FunctionName.Disabled" is working for in-process azure functions, but not for isolated functions

Comment: I meant the appsettings.json within the code. Not the one in portal.